# Bézout-type theorems over a combination of fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose we have a complex variety, say, for concreteness, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. If we intersect this with a hyperplane to get a zero-dimensional variety, then we will have (at most) two intersection points. But suppose now that we look at $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ as a real variety, setting $x = x_1 + i x_2$ and $y = y_1 + iy_2$, and expanding out to get two equations in four variables, namely,
$$x_1^2 - x_2^2 + y_1^2 - y_2^2 = 1, x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2 = 0.$$
If we intersect this with a $2$-dimensional plane to get a zero-dimensional variety $X$, how many points does $X$ have over the reals? Bézout implies that the answer is at most $4$, but can this be improved to $2$ by using that we are really working with a complex variety of degree $2$? Clearly, this is the case if our $2$-dimensional plane comes from a complex line, but does it continue to hold if it doesn't?

More generally, I'd be interested to hear if there are any interesting variants of Bézout if one mixes fields like this and whether there are any good references.

Comment: Four real points are certainly possible: e.g. take the plane $\{x_1-\sqrt{2}y_2=x_2=0\}$ and then the four points of intersection are $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=\pm(0,0,1,0),\pm(\sqrt{2},0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I suspect that rules out any general phenomenon where one can do better than Bézout, but I'd still be interested to hear from someone if there is more to be said.